# How can I return data from `$http` with a $q resolve?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-promise, angular-http

I have a javascript function which for this question I have simplified. It actually does some things to the data retrieved from the $http call and then I want that data to be made available along with a promise to the function that called it:

```
getTopics = (queryString: string) => {
        var self = this;
        var defer = self.$q.defer();
        self.$http({
            // cache: true,
            url: self.ac.dataServer + '/api/Topic/GetMapData' + queryString,
            method: "GET"
        })
            .success((data) => {

                var output: ITopics = {
                    details: data
                }
                // output is correctly populated with data
                defer.resolve(output);

                // I also tried this and it get seen in the calling function either
                // defer.resolve('abc');
            })
        return defer.promise;
    };
```

This calls it:

```
return topicService.getTopics("/" + subjectService.subject.id)
       .then((data) => {
           // data seems to be not defined
           var x = data;
});
```

Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong. I thought the resolve would return data also but it seems not to be doing so.

Comment: Are you sure that `success` is being called? Try deleting `: void` too

Comment: Yes it stops at var x = data in the debugger.  But when I hover over data the chrome debugger does not show anything.

Comment: Looks like you are using typescript, but you are declaring your `data` result as `void` rather than e.g. `any`. I don't know for certain but void sounds like no real content

Comment: I deleted : void and it is still the same.  it goes to var x = data but data shows nothing. If I check the other point and look at output it is correctly populated with data

Comment: maybe because you forgot the closing tag of '{' in topicService. try adding '}' after the var x = data;

Comment: @RGraham - yes it's populated there

Comment: @Anne Why the reference to `self`? Why are the `$q` and `$http` dependencies not resolved through injection?

Comment: this is part of a much larger service.  Just this part of the code is not working.  $q and $http are injected into the service

Comment: @Anne I still can't see why you'd need `this` to reference services, but OK. Here is a minimal reproduction of the code you've posted. Assuming your AJAX code returns as you expect, the code works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/xnx24swp/

Comment: @Anne it seems to me that you are wrapping promises around promises for no particular reason. This is called the deffered-anti-pattern, I think you should remove the wrapping in $q and return the $httpPromise from $http service.

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax, which is what I swtiched to when I moved some existing `$q` code to ES6

```
getTopics(queryString) {
    return this.$q((resolve, reject) => {
        this.$http.get(self.ac.dataServer + '/api/Topic/GetMapData' + queryString)
        .success((data) => {
            resolve({details: data});
        })
        .error( (err) => reject(err) );
    });
}
```

or much better, as suggested by Bergi:

```
getTopics(queryString) {
    return this.$http.get(self.ac.dataServer + '/api/Topic/GetMapData' + queryString)
        .then( data => ({details: data}) );
    });
}
```

`$http.get().then(...)` is itself a promise that can be further used by the calling code.

Comment: Avoid the [promise construction antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the tip - I've changed in my own code but am not sure exactly how Anne should now change hers

Comment: In this case, it's just `getTopics(…) { return $http.get(…).then(data => ({details:data})); }`. Can you help us improving the answers to the linked question? What parts of them are hard to understand?

Comment: Thanks - hopefully I have interpreted you correctly

Comment: Those parens around the object literal are very important in arrow functions :-)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's a matter of personal preference, but I use the `$q.defer()` technique to "promisify" a synchronous function. In case of something that's already asynchronous, i.e, already a promise, like `$http` and `$timeout`, I set a success handler using the `then` function, modify the result as necessary and return the object as a promise using `$q.when()`

Refer to the `when` function in the [$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

I've created a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hr4qWapz4q7fkDIJX6ou?p=preview) (in Javascript) that demonstrates the use of `$q.when` in this situation. Relevant code:

```
$scope.results = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$scope.getTopics = function() {

  //Replace $timeout with $http
  // $http({
  // }).then....

  return $timeout(function() {
      console.log('Simulating HTTP response');
      return $scope.results;
    }, 1500)
    .then(function(res) {
      var updatedRes = [];
      //Modify the HTTP/timeout results
      console.log('Modifying HTTP/timeout result');
      angular.forEach(res, function(item) {
        item = item + '1';
        updatedRes.push(item);
      });

      //Wrap the result object in $q.when to create a promise
      return $q.when(updatedRes);
    });
};

$scope.getTopics().then(function(data) {
  console.log('Using the modified result');
  $scope.updatedResults = data;
  console.log('getTopics result = ', data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
return topicService.getTopics("/" + subjectService.subject.id)
   .then((data): void => {
       // data seems to be not defined
       var x = data;
   } // ADDED
);
```

I think it's because of the missing } in the code that's why data doesn't have any value in the getTopics function.

Comment: I'm sorry this was just a mistake when I was entering the question.  The  } is actually there in my code.